# Excel VBA out of range

Tags: vba, csv, excel

I have found this code and I have tried to alter it so the imported data is stored in another sheet.

The first code was `Destination:=ActiveCell` and I've tried to change it so the data is stored in another sheet.
I have also tried it with this: `Destination:=Workbook.Sheets(CSV).Cells(1, 1))` but it does not work either.

I was also looking for code to automatically select the newest csv file with the name export-price but I haven't found a solution for this yet.

```
Sub LoadProducts()
    Dim fileName As String, folder As String

    folder = "C:\Users\CP\Downloads\"
    fileName = ActiveCell.Value

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select


    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables _
        .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & folder & fileName, Destination:=Workbook.Sheets(CSV).Cells(1, 1))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your objects correctly and then use them. Here is an example. Change as applicable.

```
Dim wb As Workbook, thiswb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, thisws As Worksheet

'~~> Change as applicable
Set thiswb = ThisWorkbook
Set thisws = thiswb.Sheets("Sheet1")

CSV = "Sheet1"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Blah Blah.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets(CSV)

With thisws.QueryTables _
    .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & folder & Filename, Destination:=ws.Cells(1, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks for you awnser. Now on the folder there will be more the one csv file to import. When the user downloads a new one windows gives it a new number

export-price.csv
export-price(2).csv
export-price(3).csv
export-price(4).csv

Can i use a code to select the newest csv file contaning export-price?

Comment: Yes you can do that or you can use a file dialog to let the user select the file.

Comment: Do you know how I do that

Comment: Yes, Search SO or in fact Excel's inbuit help on `Application.Getopenfilename` :) There is a complete code example.